# Не получается перенести приложение с rails 4.2.1 на rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, миграция

Нужно перенести приложение с 4.2.1 на 5.1**

```
rails app:update
ИЛИ
rake rails:update
```

Получаю

```
   rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- routing_filter/adapters/rails_5
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'    
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/routing-filter-0.3.1/lib/routing_filter.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/routing-filter-0.3.1/lib/routing-filter.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require' 
/home/vladislav/flashcards/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vladislav/flashcards/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/vladislav/flashcards/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails  /commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `block in perform'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails    /commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/home/vladislav/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

ОС Ubuntu 16.04

```
Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.3'
gem 'rails', '5.1.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails' И так далее..

Bundle update && Bundle
```

успешно прошёл и установил все гемы.

Comment: [`routing-filter` не поддерживает Rails 5.1.](https://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter/blob/master/routing-filter.gemspec#L4) Не знаю, почему Bundler вам не дал об этом знать.

Comment: Спасибо, дело действительно было в нём. на 5.0.2 переход получился плавный и без ошибок

Comment: Учитесь читать стектрейсы ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯